# Need help to format data using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fetching data from api, the data is in following format

```
{'name':'sam', 'id':'001','page':[{'id':'111','ques':[{'id':'211','ans':[{'choice':'2111','row':'2225'}]},
                        {'id':'311','ans':[{'choice':'2511','row':'2265'}]},
                        {'id':'211','ans':[{'choice':'2111','row':'2225'}]}]}],'path':'xxx','stat':'done'}
```

I want to format this output as below :

```
{'name':'sam', 'id':'001','page':[{'id':'111','ques':[{'id':'211','ans':[{'choice':'2111','row':'2225'}]}}],'path':'xxx','stat':'done'}

{'name':'sam', 'id':'001','page':[{'id':'111','ques':[{'id':'311','ans':[{'choice':'2511','row':'2265'}]}}],'path':'xxx','stat':'done'}

{'name':'sam', 'id':'001','page':[{'id':'111','ques':[{'id':'211','ans':[{'choice':'2111','row':'2225'}]}]}],'path':'xxx','stat':'done'}
```

Can someone help me to get the desired output in python ?thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if `d` is your original dictionary:

```
for page in d["page"]:
    {
      "name": d["name"],
      # etc
      "page": [page],
    }
```

Simple for loop, with a copy of the attributes you want to copy. The better option is probably to first create a copy of the dictionary without page:

```
ref = dict(d)
del ref["page"]
```

and use it to create a new version and then add "page".

Comment: Thanks for the response. To be precise  it's not a dictionary, it is one of an element in a list. list has many elements of above format where each element is of type dictionary. I would like to format each element in the list.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little bit confused, what is not a dictionary?

Comment: can you provide me email?, so that I can explain this in detail with docs

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not doing fixes over email, and the goal of SO is to exchange information and provide resources for the other users as well.

Comment: No issue, pls refer to this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53105545/how-to-achieve-the-output-as-in-below-dataframes